# How to filter elements with python xml.etree ElementTree class

Tags: python, xml, xsd, elementtree

I am parsing and XSD to try and get a unique list of attributes. The format of the XSD is ...

```
<xsd:ComplexType name=main_value>
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name=value1 />
        <xsd:element name=value2 />
        <xsd:element name=value3 />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:ComplexType>
<xsd:ComplextType name=value1 >
    <xsd:all>
        <element maxOccurs=1 minOccurs=1 name="Attribute1">
        <element maxOccurs=1 minOccurs=0 name="Attribute2">
        <element maxOccurs=1 minOccurs=0 name="Attribute3">
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

There is a top level complexType that is a list of complexTypes. For example the top level ComplexType might be something like 'Animal', and it would list sub category complexTypes: AnimalFood, AnimalAccessories, etc. Than the sub-category complexTypes are listed out with their attributes underneath them, i.e. shortDescription, keyFeatures, brand, etc.

Currently this is how I'm tapping into those elements, and extracting their attributes.

```
for child in document_tree.getroot():
    for grandchild in child:
        for greatgrandchild in grandchild:
            if not dict(greatgrandchild.attrib.items()).get('type'):
                attributes.append(dict(greatgrandchild.attrib.items()).get('name'))
```

I wanted to try and filter by element type. For example, all the attributes I need are nested in an 'all' element. Is there a way with xml.etree.ElementTree where you can filter the whole XSD/XML schema by a certain attribute type.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some kind of visitor function to search recursively.

The following snippet works as a self-contained example for me:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<myxsd><ComplexType name="main_value">
    <choice>
        <element name="value1" />
        <element name="value2" />
        <element name="value3" />
    </choice>
</ComplexType>
<ComplextType name="value1">
    <all>
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Attribute1" />
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Attribute2" />
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Attribute3" />
    </all>
    <a><b><c><d><e><f>
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Attribute4" />
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Attribute5" />
        <element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Attribute6" />
    </f></e></d></c></b></a>
</ComplextType></myxsd>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)

attributes = []

def visit(node):
    if node.tag == "element":
        name = node.attrib.get("name")
        if name is not None:
            attributes.append(name)
    for child in node:
        visit(child)

visit(root)                

print(attributes)
```